# How to obtain specific distance between image and caption in beamer?

Tags: beamer, captions, lengths

I'm trying to set the the caption `1pt` below the image in a figure in `beamer`. If I set `\abovecaptionskip` to `0pt` there is still a gap between the image and the caption. This results from the `\baselineskip` being larger than the fontsize (default `10pt`/`12pt`). I can achieve a zero distance by using the caption package as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \textcolor{yellow}{\vrule width \linewidth height .5\textheight depth 0pt\relax}
    \caption{Caption}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Did you notice `compatibility=false`? That's not good practice! `caption` doesn't support modifying beamer captions in newer version.

The question is: *How to obtain a specific distance between image and caption in beamer without using any unsupported package?* In my case the specific distance would be `1pt`.

It would be nice to have a `beamer` only solution without any extra packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option, not needing calculations. You can kill the interline skip before the caption in the definition of  the internal `\beamer@makecaption` command, which actually typesets the caption. The original definition (in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`) is

```
\long\def\beamer@makecaption#1#2{%
  \def\insertcaptionname{\csname#1name\endcsname}%
  \def\insertcaptionnumber{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \def\insertcaption{#2}%
  \nobreak\vskip\abovecaptionskip\nobreak
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\usebeamertemplate**{caption}}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    \usebeamertemplate**{caption}\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \nobreak\vskip\belowcaptionskip\nobreak
  }
```

so you can insert `\nointerlineskip` after the first `\nobreak`, as in

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@makecaption#1#2{%
  \def\insertcaptionname{\csname#1name\endcsname}%
  \def\insertcaptionnumber{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \def\insertcaption{#2}%
  \nobreak\nointerlineskip\vskip\abovecaptionskip\nobreak
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\usebeamertemplate**{caption}}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    \usebeamertemplate**{caption}\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \nobreak\vskip\belowcaptionskip\nobreak
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{0pt}
\begin{figure}
\rule{3cm}{1cm}
\caption{Test with \texttt{0pt} and some more text so the caption will span more than one line}
\end{figure}
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{1pt}
\begin{figure}
\rule{3cm}{1cm}
\caption{Test with \texttt{1pt} and some more text so the caption will span more than one line}
\end{figure}
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{10pt}
\begin{figure}
\rule{3cm}{1cm}
\caption{Test with \texttt{10pt} and some more text so the caption will span more than one line}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or you can patch the command to introduce the change simplifying the code, as in the following example:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@makecaption}
  {\nobreak}
  {\nobreak\nointerlineskip}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're only including text in the caption, the maximum height should be as tall as `\figurename` (or `\tablename`, in the case of a table). As such, capturing `\figurename` in a box (say `\captionsavebox`) and measuring its height allows you to adjust `\abovecaptionskip` to suit your needs exactly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newsavebox{\captionsavebox}
\savebox{\captionsavebox}{\figurename}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \textcolor{yellow}{\vrule width \linewidth height .5\textheight depth 0pt\relax}
    \caption{Caption}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{\dimexpr-\baselineskip+\ht\captionsavebox+1pt}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \textcolor{yellow}{\vrule width \linewidth height .5\textheight depth 0pt\relax}
    \caption{Caption}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The `\caption` setup in [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) very much mimics that of a regular caption. Here's the "make caption" macro (from [`beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbaselocalstructure.sty)):

```
\long\def\beamer@makecaption#1#2{%
  \def\insertcaptionname{\csname#1name\endcsname}%
  \def\insertcaptionnumber{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \def\insertcaption{#2}%
  \nobreak\vskip\abovecaptionskip\nobreak
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\usebeamertemplate**{caption}}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    \usebeamertemplate**{caption}\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \nobreak\vskip\belowcaptionskip\nobreak}
```